# Memcached::getMulti() returning an empty array

Tags: php, memcached

Tried using `Memcached::getMulti()` instead of fetching one cache key at a time.
The result was an empty array(). I used the debugger to ensure that I was passing an indexed array of keys and I made sure the keys were in cache. Why is memcached returning an empty array when I know for sure the keys exist?

```
$mc->get('MYKEY');
```

vs.

```
$mc->getMulti(array([0]=>'MYKEY0',[1]=>'MYKEY1',[2]=>'MYKEY2'));
```

Comment: Post some code. This isn't a forum for theory.

Comment: Does the fetching one cache key at a time work for this?

Comment: @Hast: Yep! It works flawlessly!

Comment: @RobAdams: It's a straight forward get(key) vs getMulti(array_of_keys)